# ¿Cómo consigo que mi botón play se cambie a pause?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css

Muy buenas a todos.
En una web en la que estoy trabajando tengo un pequeño botón play/pause cuyo objetivo es que al hacer click la música comience a sonar y el "icono" se convierta en pause. A su vez, cuando la música esté sonando, si vuelves a pulsar en el, la música se pare y el botón vuelva a su estado "icono play".
Este es mi código

```
<audio preload="none" id="myAudio1" src="audio/vienen-a-robar.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

css

```
.play-btn{
 background-color: green;
 background-image: url(url/play.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 23px;
 width: 23px;
}
.pause-btn{
 background-image: url(url/pause.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 23px;
 width: 23px;
 background-color: red;
}
```

Javascript

```
var currentsound;
function play_pause(player) {
var myAudio = document.getElementById(player);
    if(myAudio.paused) {
    myAudio.play();
    } else{
    myAudio.pause();
    }
if ("play-btn"){
$( ".play-btn" ).addClass( "pause-btn" );
} else {
$( ".play-btn" ).removeClass( "pause-btn" );
}
```

Con este código consigo que el "Botón de play" se convierte en pause, pero no viceversa. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

Al parecer solo necesitas hacer unas modificaciones al código y listo

```
var currentsound;
function play_pause(player) {
   var myAudio = document.getElementById(player);
   if(myAudio.paused) {
       myAudio.play();
       $( ".play-btn" ).removeClass( "pause-btn" );
       $( ".play-btn" ).addClass( "play-btn" ); 
   } else{
       myAudio.pause();
       $( ".play-btn" ).removeClass( "play-btn" );
       $( ".play-btn" ).addClass( "pause-btn" ); 
   }
}
```